# Compare two powers

Tags: logarithms

how can I compare these powers:   $3^{500}$ and $5^{300}$
What I did is:

$\log_3(3^{500})$   and $\log_3(5^{300})$
So I have

$500$ and $\log_3(5^{300})$
Now I do not know what to do. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would suggest using a base that is available directly on your calculator, base $10$ or base $e$ (natural logarithm). Whatever base you use, $\log(3^{500})=500\log 3$. But because these numbers are **very** special, there is a shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of messing things up with logarithms: since clearly $\;3^5>5^3\;$ and$$500=5\cdot 100\;,\;\;300=3\cdot 100\implies$$

$$3^{500}=\left(3^5\right)^{100}>\left(5^3\right)^{100}=5^{300}$$

Comment: Is this a property that if the exponential 5 is bigger than the base 3 then the power 5^3<3^5 ?

Comment: @John, just calculate by hand! $\;3^5=243\;,\;\;5^3=125\;$ ...

Comment: :) Thank you , excuse me it was a stupid question

Answer (score 0):

Take the one hundreth root of both numbers. Then you're left with comparing $3^5=243$ and $5^3=125$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt3\simeq1.7\iff3\sqrt3\simeq5\iff\log_35^{300}=300\cdot\log_35\simeq300\cdot\log_3\Big(3\sqrt3\Big)=300\cdot\Big(1+\frac12\Big)$ $=300+150=450$.